# Mac OS: ROS Build Errors (Indigo)

Tags: ros, build, mac, macosx, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using this: https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx
Trying to install Indigo. (I got the same error for Jade - after failing I uninstalled Brew, deleted directories)

OS X Yosemite, ver 10.10.5

brew --version : 0.9.5 (git revision d430d; last commit 2015-10-05)

pip --version : pip 7.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
    [ 25%] Built target pcl_ros_gencfg
    Scanning dependencies of target pointcloud_to_pcd
    [ 26%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pointcloud_to_pcd.dir/tools/pointcloud_to_pcd.cpp.o
    [ 28%] Linking CXX executable /Users/anon/indigo_desktop_full_ws/devel/lib/pcl_ros/convert_pcd_to_image
    ld: library not found for -lvtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[2]: *** [/Users/anon/indigo_desktop_full_ws/devel/lib/pcl_ros/convert_pcd_to_image] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/convert_pcd_to_image.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    [ 30%] Linking CXX executable /Users/anon/indigo_desktop_full_ws/devel/lib/pcl_ros/pcd_to_pointcloud
    ld: library not found for -lvtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[2]: *** [/Users/anon/indigo_desktop_full_ws/devel/lib/pcl_ros/pcd_to_pointcloud] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcd_to_pointcloud.dir/all] Error 2
    [ 31%] Linking CXX executable /Users/anon/indigo_desktop_full_ws/devel/lib/pcl_ros/convert_pointcloud_to_image
    ld: library not found for -lvtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[2]: *** [/Users/anon/indigo_desktop_full_ws/devel/lib/pcl_ros/convert_pointcloud_to_image] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/convert_pointcloud_to_image.dir/all] Error 2
    [ 33%] Linking CXX executable /Users/anon/indigo_desktop_full_ws/devel/lib/pcl_ros/pointcloud_to_pcd
    ld: library not found for -lvtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[2]: *** [/Users/anon/indigo_desktop_full_ws/devel/lib/pcl_ros/pointcloud_to_pcd] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pointcloud_to_pcd.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    [pcl_ros] <== '/Users/anon/indigo_desktop_full_ws/build/pcl_ros/build_env.sh /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=3,4 -j' failed with return code '2'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218682/mac-os:-ros-build-errors-(indigo)/) by [japzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24275/japzi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, thanks for trying out the Mac build. I'm pretty sure this is a regression, so I've responded to the discussion on the [Github ticket](https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx/issues/13). Let's continue the conversation there.

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2015-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1